High power consumption Radio device: ideapad_acpi consuming 9 watts on Lenovo Legion 5 pro 16ARX8
Hey i have been running linux on the laptop for a while and today i found out that the laptop is consuming almost 9 watts for Radio device: ideapad_acpi.
I tried disabling wifi from bios,blacklisted ethernet and btusb but still it didn't help.
I tried tuning in powertop but it didn't help. I also have autocpufreq installed.
Software Stack:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS,
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic,
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7745HX with Radeon Graphics,
AMD ATI 05:00.0 Raphael,
Host: 82WM Legion Pro 5 16ARX8

Does this answer your question? How to tweak Powertop to reduce power consumption?

Sorry for that :)  I have edited the orginal post and added the details you guys needed.

I believe 9 watts is a bit excessive for a wifi device. I don't know if i can believe the readings from powertop though?

update. wifi shows up as a different output in powertop,  Network interface: wlo1 (mt7921e) consuming 1.5 watts. So what is this Radio device: ideapad_acpi

Check lsmod | grep ideapad and that might reveal the module name

i used the command and it returnedtinu@tinu-Legion-Pro-5-16ARX8:~$ lsmod | grep ideapad ideapad_laptop         57344  0 sparse_keymap          12288  1 ideapad_laptop platform_profile       12288  1 ideapad_laptop video                  73728  2 amdgpu,ideapad_laptop wmi                    32768  3 video,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop'
@Jeremy31

sorry for the formatting

I think you will want to leave it alone, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI

Now it has magically vanished and it's showing Display backlight is consuming 7 watts
